# Disable On-screen Keyboard 18.04 at all times

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I can't disable the on-screen keyboard after a fresh install of 18.04. I have a Dell XPS 13 that is equipped with both a touch screen and keyboard. I use the touch screen regularly to switch between windows, but every time I touch a window I now have this useless on-screen keyboard pop-up.

I've disabled the screen keyboard in the universal access settings menu. I've also installed the caribou blocker program for firefox (which only works some of the time). I'm running gnome v 3.28, where this issue was supposed to be fixed.

Any ideas on what else I can try to get my touchscreen back?

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug, reported [here in the GNOME bug tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/872).

Comment: Some folks suggested [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/) as a workaround. If you can investigate and add anything like that to your answer it would help

Comment: I've tried the extension but it does not work with my version of gnome-shell (the one coming with Ubuntu 20.04) - people in other places report it working in 18.04